# Access user attributes in Keycloak terms.ftl

Tags: themes, keycloak

I am trying to access the user attributes in a custom theme that I am developing. Under theme_folder/login/terms.ftl I want to access some of the user attributes to display the respective Terms and Conditions for each user. Somehow user is always null in the terms.ftl.

Does anyone know if it is possible to reach the user attributes in terms.ftl?